# Less files not getting compiled immediately

Tags: css, django, less, django-staticfiles, django-static

I am working on a django application and using less for generating CSS.
On my localhost, everything works fine and changing less file updates CSS almost immediately.

However, when I deploy to server (apache2, wsgi), the old css files are rendered for a long time.
I was wondering how can I fix this?
Is there a way I can forcefully invalidate the precompiler cache so that new CSS files are generated?

Thank you

Comment: are you using `{% compress %}`?

Comment: No. I will try doing that.

Comment: compress to to compress (minify) the files. How is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using `django_compressor` for managing Sass. In my deployment script I use the django_compressor compress offline setting, which generates a new filename for the compressed static files. I started doing this to get around server caching and browser caching problems, and it's been scaling nicely as my static files have gotten larger.

[Here's the docs](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#pre-compression) on offline compression or precompression

In my deployment script I run `manage.py compress` which generates the new file names.

This probably isn't the simplest solution but it's a good time investment to set up.

Comment: How is this relevant? This is for compressing the css files. I am not worried about compression. I am interested to generate css from the less files.

Comment: There's an option to turn off the compression if you don't want it. Even without compression I find that compressor is a good tool for managing Sass and Less files during deployment. Compressor will take one or multiple Less files and generate a css file with a unique name per deployment, getting around any caching problems.